# Installing multiple MSI's dynamically Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

I have three windows based application. I need to deploy them into a single msi file. The first two files are kinda like the check for the proper computer, like the specific computer name and login username. The problem I have is that how can I deploy all these three application into one msi file. And the installation goes like this ?:
1: Install the window application A
2: If application doesn't install properly then stop installation and delete application B and application C. However if everything goes fine then install the final main application, Application C.

Addition information: The application A and Application B is basically kinda checking the username and proper name of the computer and then printing out the specified values into the registry.

Appreciate help in advance :)

Comment: "How do you install the contents of multiple MSIs with one atomic installation operation?". Or, perhaps, "how do you deploy multiple applications into one MSI?".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the VS Setup Project installer, this is a little more difficult than it has to be but not by much.

The first thing you should do is pick a "primary" application. This application's installer will be the one invoked by the user to install all three and will control the other two.

Now, deploy the other two applications into their MSI files. This process is relatively straightforward; the only thing you must do is ensure that any custom information that may be needed by the setup wizard can be defined using command-line parameters, and that the installation can be performed in an unattended manner. VS Setup Projects allow both of these; you have to define the parameter name of any custom field in your wizard, but given that the unattended feature is "free". Once these MSIs are built, add them as files to be installed to the main application directory of the primary app.

Now, you must define custom actions in the installer of the primary application. This is done by creating a class inheriting from System.Configuration.Install.Installer, decorating it with a RunInstaller attribute, and specifying this Installer class's project as a set of Custom Actions for the installer.

In the Installer class, override the OnAfterInstall, OnBeforeUninstall, and OnRollback methods. In the OnAfterInstall method, call Process.Start to invoke MsiExec.exe with the /I option to install, passing the path and name of the first application's MSI, and specifying the "/q" option to perform the install silently as well as any properties which must be set (installation parameters; path, install level/components, app settings, etc). Repeat for the other application, then repeat the process with the OnBeforeUninstall and OnRollback methods, but specifying the /x option to uninstall the MSIs.

When you're done, you should have a single MSI containing the other two MSIs, that when installed will silently install the other two and when uninstalled will uninstall the other two. For more advanced installation control, you can differentiate between an "install" and a "modification/repair" by examining the savedState dictionary in the handlers (during a repair, you should repair the child apps instead of trying to reinstall them), and you may make installation of the other two applications optional using a Components dialog in the install process (the information will be passed to the custom action handlers, and can also be used to choose whether to copy one or both MSIs to the primary app directory). Finally, you may choose to override OnAfterCommit and remove the MSIs (but if you do so, you will have to uninstall the child packages using Windows' retained copy of the MSI, which can be tricky to find).